# Scala error: X value is not a member of Y --> property not visible despite being declared in default constructor

Tags: scala

I have a file **Post.scala** in which I have the following code:

```
object Post {
  def dummyPost(): Post = {
    return new Post()
  }
}

class Post(postId: String, user: User, createdTime: Long, message: Option[String], imgUrl: Option[String]) {

  // constructor to create a dummy post when the emergency button is pressed
  private def this() {
    this("0", new User("0", "Notknopf", HardwareButton), System.currentTimeMillis / 1000, None, None)
  }

  def this(facebookPost: FacebookPost) {
    this(facebookPost.id, new User(facebookPost.from), facebookPost.created_time, facebookPost.message, facebookPost.full_picture)
  }

  def this(instagramPost: InstagramPost) {
    this(instagramPost.id, new User(instagramPost.user), instagramPost.created_time, None, instagramPost.imgURL)
  }

}
```

Then in another class, I am using `Post` like so:

```
...
def receive = {

    case DispenseItem(post: Post) =>
      Logger.debug("DispenseItem received for user: " + post.user.displayName)
...
```

However, the compiler complains that `value user is not a member of Models.Post`. Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong? Shouldn't the properties that are declared in the default constructor right after the class's name be public and accessible from anywhere?

Comment: all right, I guess it was a duplicate! thanks for the hint though, that solved my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for fields of a constructor to be visible outside a non-case class, you must declare them with `val`, like so:

```
class Post(val postId: String, val user: User, val createdTime: Long, val message: Option[String], val imgUrl: Option[String])
```